# How do I make a query shorter and neater?

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to make This query more understandable and neater. But im not sure how to?

```
 SELECT a.Patient_id, COUNT (p.Person_id) AS "Number of Operations", SUM (w.Daily_charge * (a.Discharge_date - a.Admission_date) + ot.Theatre_fee + b.Charges + c.Charges ) AS "Total Payment"
    FROM person p, admission a, ward w, operation o, operation_type ot, staff b, staff c
    WHERE w.Ward_code = a.Ward_code AND p.Person_id = a.Patient_id
    AND a.Admission_id = o.Admission_id AND ot.Op_code = o.Actual_op
    AND o.Surgeon = b.Person_id AND o.Anaesthetist = c.Person_id
    GROUP BY a.Patient_id, p.Person_id
    ORDER BY COUNT (p.Person_id) DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

[image: The output]

Comment: Using ANSI-92 (that's year 1992!) style joins and some reasonable indenting would go a long way

Comment: I wouldn't use spaces in column aliases either; let the front end worry about formatting(localizing) the column name in some report. `COUNT(*)`  will suffice here too.. You should consider putting something in the where clause that is more restrictive/useful than making the db perform some massive join, sort and discard operation just to find out the person who's had the least number of operations (maybe that truly is what you want to know.. but it feels like a particularly uninformative SQL without some other sensible restrictions in the where clause)

Comment: ps; *shorter and neater* is probably unattainable; your query is relatively short because it is not neat - brevity does not necessarily equal clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any decent formatter would do it for you.

Other than that,

- `JOIN` instead of comma-separate tables in the `FROM` clause
- remove `p.person_id` from `group by` clause, there's no use of it as it is

  - equal to `a.patient_id` which is correctly put into the clause,
  - not part of the `select` statement's column list

So:

```
select a.patient_id, 
       count (p.person_id) as "number of operations", 
       sum (w.daily_charge * (a.discharge_date - a.admission_date) + 
            ot.theatre_fee + b.charges + c.charges 
           ) as "total payment"
  from person p join admission a       on a.patient_id   = p.person_id
                join ward w            on w.ward_code    = a.ward_code
                join operation o       on o.admission_id = a.admission_id
                join operation_type ot on ot.op_code     = o.actual_op
                join staff b           on o.surgeon      = b.person_id
                join staff c           on o.anaesthetist = c.person_id
group by a.patient_id
order by count (p.person_id) desc 
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Comment: not a massive fan of formatters that change the indent level depending on the length of tablenames/aliases etc; I prefer to use indent as an indication of query level

Comment: @Caius, then only "decent" formatter I know is the one in TOAD. All others are less decent. A keyboard combination formats my code *uniformly*, I'm used to it and I kind of like it. Much easier/faster than doing everything manually.

Comment: Here's my basic rules for formatting SQL statements: 1) every sub-phrase (WHERE, FROM, GROUP BY, etc) starts on a new line and is appropriately indented 2) every column in a list (in the SELECT, in the GROUP BY, etc) starts on a new line, indented  3) every table name/join in the WHERE starts a new line, and is appropriately indented.   Crude rule: every comma denotes a separation of a list, so should trigger a new line and appropriate indention for that list.

Comment: And while old hands feel that automatic formatters have "issues" (and rightfully so), if someone like the OP has no idea about formatting, they could do worse than use an automated formatter and start observing what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no perfect formatter, although as Ed mentioned in the comments, they can be a start if you review the settings carefully. (It's a tradition in the industry that the default formatter settings are always horrible.)

It's also been said (I think by Steven Feuerstein) that you should only set formatting rules that are supported by your formatter, and of course he makes a good point. But taken with the limitations of all formatters, an industry tradition for horrible formatting and the impossibility of consistent rules for formatting SQL anyway, that puts us PL/SQL developers in a difficult position.

I'd say the first principle of computer code layout is to use vertically aligned blocks to indicate dependency levels (similar to the [grids used in graphic design](https://www.graphic-design-institute.com/visual-grammar/types-grid-system-useful-layout-making/)). A lot of the choices then become about [how to apply that principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).

We then need to separate the code into logical sections, but at the same time not let it sprawl down the page unnecessarily. I think this is difficult for automated formatters as the rules become a bit fuzzy, e.g. for a join with only one condition I keep it on one line, but if there is more than one I start splitting it out onto multiple lines, one per `on` or `and` keyword. The same goes for your complex `sum()` expression - normally I would place it all on one line, but if it aids readability then I split it up.

Finally, opinions vary on where to place commas in stacked lists, of which SQL has a lot. I say they go on the left, to act like bullet points and also make it easier to add items to the ends of lists. Others will disagree.

```
select ad.patient_id
     , count(*) as "Number of Operations"
     , sum(
           wa.daily_charge * (ad.discharge_date - ad.admission_date)
           + ot.theatre_fee + ss.charges + sa.charges
       ) as "Total Payment"
from   person pr
       join admission ad on ad.patient_id = pr.person_id
       join ward wa on wa.ward_code = ad.ward_code
       join operation op on op.admission_id = ad.admission_id
       join operation_type ot on ot.op_code = op.actual_op
       join staff ss on ss.person_id = op.surgeon
       join staff sa on sa.person_id = op.anaesthetist
group by ad.patient_id
order by count(*) desc
fetch first row only;
```